# C++ application using library says no members detected

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I have an application that uses a bunch of math formulas in a DOS choose a number style. So I made a static library and I currently have them linked but when I try using a function it will say no members detected. Here's my code (the important parts):
// The library header file:

```
namespace Library_ {
static float min, max, n, rem, i, r, l, w, m, v, k, r1, r2, r3, r4, h, b,
       b1, b2, s, value, count = 0; static float f = 1;

static class Main
{
public:
    class Geometry_2Dimensional
    {
        static void rectangle();
        static void circle();
        static void ETGRadius();
        static void ETGSide();
    };

    class Geometry_3Dimensional
    {
        static void prismRectangle();
        static void prismTriangle();
        static void cylinder();
        static void sphere();
    };

    class Computing
    {
        static void rng();
        static void binary(int num);
    };

    class Number_Theory
    {
        static void average();
        static void primeCheck();
        static void primeFactors();
        static void factorial();
    };

    static void Error();
};
}
```

// The Library source file:

```
include "CalculatorLib.h"
include <stdexcept>
include <iostream>
include <time.h>
include <math.h>
include <cstdlib>
include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

namespace Library_
{
void Main::Error()
{
    cout << "Not a valid option." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void Main::Geometry_2Dimensional::rectangle()
{
    cout << "Length: "; cin >> l;
    cout << "Width: "; cin >> w;
    cout << "Area: " << l * w << "\nPerimeter: " << (2 * l) + (2 * w) << 
endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Geometry_2Dimensional::circle()
{
    cout << "Radius: "; cin >> r;
    cout << "Area: " << r * 3.14 * r << "\nCircumference: " << r * 6.28 << 
endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Geometry_2Dimensional::ETGRadius()
{
    cout << "Integer part: "; cin >> r1;
    cout << "Radicant: "; cin >> r2;
    r3 = sqrt(r2);
    m = (sqrt(3) / 3);
    if (r2 == 3)
    {
        n = r1 * 3;
        cout << "The side length of the triangle is: " << n << endl;
        v = n / 2;
        k = sqrt((n * n) - (v * v));
        cout << "The area of the triangle is: " << (k * n) / 2 << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        r4 = r3 * r1;
        n = r4 / m;
        cout << "The side length of the triangle is: " << n << endl;
        v = n / 2;
        k = sqrt((n*n) - (v*v));
        cout << "The area of the triangle is: " << (k * n) / 2 << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
void Main::Geometry_2Dimensional::ETGSide()
{
    cout << "Enter the side length: "; cin >> s;
    r = (s / 3) * sqrt(3);
    cout << "The radius of the inner circle is: " << r << endl;
    v = s / 2;
    k = sqrt((s*s) - (v*v));
    n = k * s;
    cout << "The area of the triangle is: " << n / 2 << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void Main::Geometry_3Dimensional::prismRectangle()
{
    cout << "Length: "; cin >> l;
    cout << "Width: "; cin >> w;
    cout << "Height: "; cin >> h;
    cout << "Area: " << l*w*h << "\nSurface Area: " << (2 * (l*w)) + (2 * 
(l*h)) + (2 * (h*w)) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Geometry_3Dimensional::sphere()
{
    cout << "Radius: "; cin >> r;
    cout << "Volume: " << 3.14 * (4 / 3) * r * r * r << "\nSurface Area: " 
<< 12.56 * r * r << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Geometry_3Dimensional::cylinder()
{
    cout << "Radius: "; cin >> r;
    cout << "Height: "; cin >> h;
    cout << "Volume: " << 3.14 * r * r * h << "\nSurface Area: " << 6.28 * r  
* h * (r + h) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Geometry_3Dimensional::prismTriangle()
{
    cout << "Base of the base: "; cin >> b;
    cout << "Height: "; cin >> h;
    cout << "Length: "; cin >> l;
    cout << "Other sides of base: " << "\nFirst other side: "; cin >> b1;
    cout << "Second other side: "; cin >> b2;
    cout << "Volume: " << h * b * l << "\nSurface Area: " << (2 * b * h) +  
 ((b + b1 + b2) * l) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void Main::Computing::rng()
{
    cout << "Enter the minimum: "; cin >> min;
    cout << "Enter the maximumL "; cin >> max;
    cout << "Enter the number of generations: "; cin >> n;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    unsigned first = time(NULL);
    srand(first);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        r = rand() / 100 % range + min;
        cout << r << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Computing::binary(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1)
    {
        cout << num;
        return;
    }
    rem = num % 2;
    binary(num / 2);
    cout << rem;
}

void Main::Number_Theory::average()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of values: "; cin >> n;
    float average(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> value;
        average += value;
    }
    average /= n;
    cout << "Average is " << average << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Number_Theory::factorial()
{
    cout << "Enter the number: "; cin >> n;
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++)
    {
        f *= a;
    }
    cout << "The factorial is: " << f << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
void Main::Number_Theory::primeCheck()
{
    cout << "Enter the number: "; cin >> n;
    int count = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++)
    {
        if (fmod(n, a) == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 2)
    {
        cout << "The number " << n << " is prime!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The number " << n << " is not prime." << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
void Main::Number_Theory::primeFactors()
{
    cout << "Enter the number: "; cin >> n;
    while (fmod(n, 2) == 0)
    {
        cout << "2, ";
        n /= 2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)
    {
        while (fmod(n, 1) == 0)
        {
            cout << i << ", ";
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 2)
    {
        cout << n << ", ";
    }
}
}
```

And then the main source file, that can't use any of the functions because intellisense says no members included.
Side note: I am including both the header file and using the namespace Library_.
If this seems rushed, it is because I have to get off. And also, in addition to solving this problem, can someone tell me when and when not to use static?
Thanks!

Comment: could you include your main.cpp file and linker flags and...?

Comment: @paykoob Linker flags, meaning all the includes and using's?
I am using stdafx.h, so here's everything in there:
#include "targetver.h"
#include "Library\CalculatorLib.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Library_;

Answer (score 1):

You are making so many mistakes here it is hard to know where to begin, using classes as if they were namespaces, using global variables, doing input and output in library code, not using function parameters and function returns, using static inappropriately, etc. etc. Also it is impossible to answer your question because you don't show **how** you are trying to call your functions.

I can answer one question which is 'when to use static'. At your level of experience the answer is **never use static**. You've got to learn the basics first.

Forget classes. forget namespaces, forget global variables, first learn how to how to write functions, how to use local variables, how to pass values to and return values from functions.

For example the following is perfectly acceptable beginner code

```
void Geometry_2Dimensional_ETGRadius(float r1, float r2, float& n, float& k)
{
    float r3 = sqrt(r2);
    float m = (sqrt(3) / 3);
    if (r2 == 3)
    {
        n = r1 * 3;
        float v = n / 2;
        k = sqrt((n * n) - (v * v));
    }
    else
    {
        float r4 = r3 * r1;
        n = r4 / m;
        float v = n / 2;
        k = sqrt((n*n) - (v*v));
    }
}

int main()
{
    float r1, r2, n, k;
    cout << "Integer part: "; cin >> r1;
    cout << "Radicant: "; cin >> r2;
    Geometry_2Dimensional_ETGRadius(r1, r2, n, k);
    cout << "The side length of the triangle is: " << n << endl;
    cout << "The area of the triangle is: " << (k * n) / 2 << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

See how the variables only used inside the function (`r3`, `m` etc) are declared inside the function. The values needed by the function are declared as parameters of the function (`r1`, `r2`) and the values returned by the function are declared as reference parameters (`n` and `k`). This is basic stuff and it is what you should get familiar with before you try anything more advanced.

Comment: But the whole reason why I wanted to make a library is so that my main application required less code, as all the functions and variables would be in the library and my main function would only focus on navigating through the console application and using the functions. The functions would then take care of in streaming the variables in such, so it would be like

Comment: case 1: 
Main::Geometry_2Dimensional::rectangle();

Comment: But when I do Main::Geometry_2Dimensional:: it says no members included

Comment: You can put ordinary functions in a library. You do not need namespaces or classes to make a library. You trying to do too much at once, without any understanding of what you are trying to do. The code you are trying to write would not be good code even for an experienced programmer. You have to learn the basics first.

Comment: And I know there are simpler ways of doing this, it's just a sort of coding OCD where everything has to be organized.

Comment: Well I recognise the OCD, you should resist that if you want to get things done. First program or not, you still have a lot to learn. The code you posted is terrible even if it was working. But even with that code you should be able to call the functions you have written. I can't tell you why you can't because you have not described how you try to call those functions.

Comment: I happen to have fixed it, and maybe I would have seen the error if I tried building... But the inner classes (Geometry_2Dimensional) didn't have a public: